# Tensorflow/Keras error. Why don't the input shapes match?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sequence

I've been trying to set up a sequence to sequence model with Keras. Unfortunately, I get the following error which I do not understand:

****Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 1000, 34), found shape=(1000, 34)**
******
**my model looks like this (first few layers only):**

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 1000, 34)]   0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 lstm (LSTM)                    [(None, 1000, 100),  54000       ['input_1[0][0]']                
                                 (None, 100),                                                     
                                 (None, 100)]                                                     
                                                                                                  
 lstm_1 (LSTM)                  [(None, 100),        80400       ['lstm[0][0]']                   
                                 (None, 100),                                                     
                                 (None, 100)]
```

the command to generate the input layer is as follows:

```
encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
```

and the commands I use to train the model is this:

```
history = model.fit(train_set, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=test_set, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=0, callbacks=[reduce_lr], steps_per_epoch=EVALUATION_INTERVAL)
```

my training set is of type

```
 tensorflow.python.data.ops.from_tensor_slices_op.TensorSliceDataset
```

containing both input sequences and targets.

Why  am I getting this error, even though my input data dimensions seem to match the dimensions expected by the input layer?

Many thanks!

I tried switching to plain numpy inputs, but that did not resolve the issue.

Why am I getting this error, even though my input data dimensions seem to match the dimensions expected by the input layer?

Many thanks,

Comment: Your inputs must have as first dimention the number of samples in the batch. For example if you want to process a single sequence of length=1000 and dimension=34 your input size will be (1, 1000, 34)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the problem. Defining the input layer as you suggested (I think) - tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(256,1000,34)) yields the following error: ValueError: 
Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 256, 1000, 34)

Comment: I'm not familiar with keras, but you're not supposed to modify the model architecture, you're supposed to change your input data shape. The batch size is not relevant to the model's architecture, this is why every layer has None as its first dimension

Comment: Can you specify what a sample of your data looks like? Is it a 1000 long sequence of 34-dimensional data?

Comment: Thanks I meanwhile got the model to train using a numpy input format ilo the TensorSliceDatset objects. I guess I must be doing something wrong converting numpy into that particular object. Once I find out what it is, I'll explain it here for - possibly - future reference. Thanks again.